# SQLITE - match number and generate another row with single values

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sqlite

As example of data from CSV, I have a row:

```
1;75353;CWB;114#389#115#381#11#382#117#78#118#384;1244;13;4727;15
```

I would like to get something like that:

```
1;75353;CWB;114;1244;13;4727;15
1;75353;CWB;389;1244;13;4727;15
1;75353;CWB;115;1244;13;4727;15
1;75353;CWB;381;1244;13;4727;15
1;75353;CWB;11;1244;13;4727;15
1;75353;CWB;382;1244;13;4727;15
1;75353;CWB;117;1244;13;4727;15
1;75353;CWB;78;1244;13;4727;15
1;75353;CWB;118;1244;13;4727;15
1;75353;CWB;384;1244;13;4727;15
```

I have tried to use (**I'm using SQLITE**, but I can use MariaDB if needed, also):

```
select dt2.zone_number, dt2.section_num, dt1.zone, dt1.section, dt1.local, dt1.local_name, dt1.address, dt1.neighbor
from datatable01 as dt1, datatable02 as dt2 where
(
dt1.zone = dt2.zone_number and
instr(dt2.section_num, dt1.section) > 0
)
order by dt1.zone, dt1.local
```

But... this capture any case. From `datatable02`, if `dt1.section = 11`, it's capture `114` from `dt2.section_num` (example above)

I have tried to use `regexp '[0-9]{2,3}'`, but I got error (syntax error).
Any suggestion to solve it?
Thank you.

Comment: SQL is not the "programming language" to use.

Comment: Indeed, @RickJames
Perhaps, another language is properly to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will do what you want or could be the basis of what you want :-

```
WITH midparts(w, s) AS (
    SELECT '',
            /* extract the mid-part i.e. from after CBW; to the next ; */
            substr(substr(row1,instr(row1,'CWB;')+length('CWB;')),1,instr(substr(row1,instr(row1,'CWB;')+length('CWB;')),';')-1)||'#' 
        FROM t01
    UNION ALL SELECT
    substr(s, 0, instr(s, '#')),
    substr(s, instr(s, '#')+1)
    FROM midparts WHERE s!=''
),
  /* extract the start and end (prefix and suffix) */
    startandend(prefix,suffix) AS (
    SELECT
        substr(row1,1,instr(row1,'CWB;') + length('CWB;') -1), 
        substr(substr(row1,instr(row1,'CWB;')+length('CWB;')),instr(substr(row1,instr(row1,'CWB;')+length('CWB;')),';')) 
    FROM t01
)
SELECT (SELECT prefix FROM startandend)||w||(SELECT suffix FROM startandend) AS generated FROM midparts WHERE w!='';
```

- noting that the table with the data has been named **t01** and that the row containing the data is **row1**

## Example :-

The above was tested using :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t01;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t01 (row1);
INSERT INTO t01 VALUES('1;75353;CWB;114#389#115#381#11#382#117#78#118#384;1244;13;4727;15');

WITH midparts(w, s) AS (
    SELECT '',
            /* extract the mid-part i.e. from after CBW; to the next ; */
            substr(substr(row1,instr(row1,'CWB;')+length('CWB;')),1,instr(substr(row1,instr(row1,'CWB;')+length('CWB;')),';')-1)||'#' 
        FROM t01
    UNION ALL SELECT
    substr(s, 0, instr(s, '#')),
    substr(s, instr(s, '#')+1)
    FROM midparts WHERE s!=''
),
  /* extract the start and end (prefix and suffix) */
    startandend(prefix,suffix) AS (
    SELECT
        substr(row1,1,instr(row1,'CWB;') + length('CWB;') -1), 
        substr(substr(row1,instr(row1,'CWB;')+length('CWB;')),instr(substr(row1,instr(row1,'CWB;')+length('CWB;')),';')) 
    FROM t01
)
SELECT (SELECT prefix FROM startandend)||w||(SELECT suffix FROM startandend) AS generated FROM midparts WHERE w!='';
```

## Result :-

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. Very useful when the city is CWB. When I have many other cities, I have to change each time. I have tried to use regex to get any word and space, but no success.

Anyway, your work is useful and complex. I had no idea about that complexity into SQLITE as possibility. Thank you over again.